# Page is not properly loaded in selenium

Tags: selenium

While running a selenium script in IE9 with browser compatibility set to IE7, I always observe in some screen the menu bar getting hidden & the script execution failing.  How can I solve this problem?  I'm thinking it means that the page is not properly loaded.

The website I'm testing only supports IE7 ,but I'm using IE9 with compatibility mode.

Can any one kindly guide me as to how to resolve this issue & why this issue is coming up frequently?

Comment: maybe start in the page itself. If the page supports only IE7 it really needs to be rebuilt...

Answer (score 1):

Change your browser to support IE7 compatibility mode:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-to-set-default-browser-mode-to-ie7-in-windows/9ce975db-c1ba-41f1-98cf-28ee83508110